Spring Security - Access Denied from @PreAuthorize keeps returning 500
I've implemented an AccessDeniedHandler
@Component
internal class AccessDeniedHandler : ServerAccessDeniedHandler {

    override fun handle(
        exchange: ServerWebExchange?,
        ex: AccessDeniedException?
    ): Mono<Void> {

        val response = exchange?.response ?: return Mono.empty()
        response.statusCode = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN
        response.headers.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
        response.headers.add("Authorization-Status", "Forbidden")

        // create AuthorizationException
        val authorizationException = AuthorizationException(
            type = URI.create(URIErrorTypes.FORBIDDEN.type),
            httpStatus = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN,
            title = "Authorization Failure",
            message = ex?.message ?: "Access Denied",
            cause = ex?.cause as Exception,
            ErrorCodeTypes.AUTHORIZATION_EXCEPTION.code,
            ErrorCategoryTypes.AUTHORIZATION_ERROR.type,
        )

        // convert to ProblemDetailsExtended
        val problemDetailsExtended = ProblemDetailsExtended(
            type = authorizationException.type,
            status = authorizationException.httpStatus.value(),
            title = authorizationException.title,
            detail = authorizationException.message,
            instance = null,
            code = authorizationException.code,
            errorCategory = authorizationException.errorCategory,
            errors = listOf(
                ErrorDetail(
                    detail = authorizationException.cause?.message ?: authorizationException.message,
                    code = authorizationException.code.toString()
                )
            )
        )

        // serialize to JSON
        val errorResponse = JSONUtilities.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(problemDetailsExtended)
        val responseBody = response.bufferFactory().wrap(errorResponse.toByteArray())

        return response.writeWith(Mono.just(responseBody))
    }
}

I have also implemented a Global Exception Handler for AccessDeniedException here:
@ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException::class)
    private suspend fun handleAuthorizationException(ex: AccessDeniedException): ResponseEntity<ProblemDetailsExtended> {

        val problemDetail = ProblemDetail.forStatusAndDetail(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, ex.message).apply {
            type = URI.create(URIErrorTypes.FORBIDDEN.type)
            status = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value()
            title = "Authorization Failure"
            detail = ex.message ?: "Access Denied"
        }

        val ProblemDetailsExtended = ProblemDetailsExtended(
            type = problemDetail.type,
            status = problemDetail.status,
            title = problemDetail.title,
            detail = problemDetail.detail,
            instance = problemDetail.instance,
            code = ErrorCodeTypes.AUTHORIZATION_EXCEPTION.code,
            errorCategory = ErrorCategoryTypes.AUTHORIZATION_ERROR.type,
            errors = listOf(
                ErrorDetail(
                    detail = ex.cause?.message ?: ex.message ?: "Access Denied",
                    code = ErrorCodeTypes.AUTHORIZATION_EXCEPTION.code.toString()
                )
            )
        )

        return ResponseEntity(
            ProblemDetailsExtended,
            headers,
            ProblemDetailsExtended.status ?: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()
        )
    } 

But for some reason, I'm not getting the right response back, when I hit an endpoint like:
 @GetMapping("/projects/{pid}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('contract:read_project')")
    suspend fun findAllByProjectId(
        @PathVariable pid: Long
    ): ResponseEntity<Flow<ContractEntity?>> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val contracts = contractService.findAllByProjectId(pid)
            ResponseEntity.ok(contracts)
        }
    }

I keep getting this back - as though Spring is seeing it as a generic 500 error?

I'm not sure where I may be going wrong. I do have an error handler for base exceptions
@ExceptionHandler(Exception::class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR), 

But if I disable that, I then get this...(which is showing the results from my AuthenticationEntryPoint handler.

So, I am quite confused why neither of my Access Denied handlers are working? Should I be using AuthorizationDeniedException instead of AccessDeniedException?
